# Maven cannot find ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, maven, android-support-library

I have run into a curious case.  Implemented a sliding menu for a project using the Android support framework (ie. ActionBarDrawerToggle).  Works fine in Eclipse, can deploy just fine to my tethered phone.  However, if I compile using Maven, all of the classes that have an import of android.support.v4 fail with messages such "package android.support.v4.app does not exist" and "BaseActivity.java:89: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol  : class ActionBarDrawerToggle".

I have tried attempted to place a support-v4 dependency in my pom.xml (both r6 and r7) but with no luck.  The correct android-support-v4.jar is in the /libs directory (or Eclipse would have issues) so I am at of a bit of a loss on what Maven is looking for.  It is strange as I have a similar setup for another project on the same laptop and machine and can use Maven just fine for *.apk creation.

Thoughts on what issues Maven is having?

Answer (score 0):

The version in Maven Central is old. (You need a version newer than r6.) You can add the version that Eclipse is using as a system dependency (or install the jar into your local repository).

As a system dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>r6</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/android-support-v4.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The problem with adding it to your local repository is in this case, I was doing automated builds/tests using cloud servers.  It was difficult (though not impossible) to script/setup a local repository for that type of environment when you are doing dynamic server allocation, etc.